# Finding similar alphabel but different numeric value in a field in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server table that has customers’ records.  There’s are few customers who has multiple record with the same first name, last name, city, state, and zip and also have the same street name but different  street number.  We have one field that stores the street number and street name. Is there a way to find out who has the same first, last name, city, zip, street name but different street number?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`, `COUNT(*)` and `HAVING`.

I don't know your table structure, but a sample implementation could be:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, City, State, Zip, COUNT(*)
FROM Customers
GROUP BY FirstName, LastName, City, State, Zip
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Close, but to answer op's exact question, you should use `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT StreetNumber)>1`

Comment: streenumberandname has both the street number and street name but I only want the records that has same street name but different street number. Your query won't work because in this case. street number is not in a different field.